# Is htmlspecialchars required if you are not outputting html?

Tags: php, xss

I have a script that registers users based on their user input. This uses prepared statements plus whitelists to prevent sql injection. But I am struggling to understand the prevention of XSS.

From what I understand, you only need to prevent XSS if you are outputting HTML onto the page? What does this mean???

Im guessing that with this register page it doesn't apply because I am not outputting HTML to the web page? Is that right?

If I was to prevent XSS, do I use htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally correct, if you are having any returned values show up on the page, or if you are inserting information into the database for later retrieval and display (like user profile information) you will want to use htmlspecialchars.

For me, when I do my user registration, if they fail to enter a correct value in an input field, I redisplay the page with the values they entered.  In this case, I have it encoded with htmlspecialchars.

If at any point ever, you plan on redisplaying the information from the DB into a webpage (as mentioned with profiles and the like) you should use htmlspecialchars.

Better safe than sorry I always say - **never** trust user input

Comment: If you are inserting data for later display you had better use `htmlspecialchars` later, when the time comes to display.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, XSS happens when you are taking the user's input un-sanitized and display in your webpage.

For example: A user inputs

```
<script>alert('hello you are hacked');</script>
```

In a text box, and you show this in your webpage after it is registered like

```
Hello, $username
```

This suddenly gets turned into

```
Hello, <script>alert('hello you are hacked');</script>
```

This is one of the form of XSS

---

One of a effiecient way to prevent XSS is like this

```
echo htmlspecialchars($varname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, you only need to prevent XSS if you are
>   outputting HTML onto the page? What does this mean???

XSS is an attack carried out by the server outputting HTML (in practice, Javascript) to the client when it did not mean to do so (and obviously when that HTML was specially crafted and supplied by a hostile user).

> Im guessing that with this register page it doesn't apply because I am
>   not outputting HTML to the web page? Is that right?

If you are not outputting *anything that comes from user input* you are safe.

> If I was to prevent XSS, do I use `htmlspecialchars`?

Yes, that is sufficient.